# How to put dictionary into array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
words = {'key': 'value', 
         'hold on': ['Huummm', 'vaysa alan bhet migam'],
         'Question': ['Hum?', 'Ha?', 'chi?', 'motevajeh nashodam?']
```

i want to get all value for (hold one) into array like this

```
word_arraay = ['Huummm', 'vaysa alan bhet migam']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding new value to list do append

```
word_arraay.append(words['hold on'])
```

If you do not initialize yet the word_arraay use this,

```
word_arraay = words['hold on']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just access the list using the right key. In your case:

```
word_arraay = words['hold on']
```